# Switching from spring JDBC template to JPA

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc

I am currently accessing data and creating queries using JDBC Template with Spring MVC framework. I have heard this is not an effective way of accessing data as it has a lot of unnecessary boilerplate code and would like to find out if there is another way of doing this E.G. Spring JPA / hibernate but still unsure how this can be achieved.

simple example using JDBC Template

```
//DAO Class
@Repository
public class UserDAO  {

 private final String GET_USERS_SQL = "SELECT users.username AS 'users.username',\n"
        + "      users.enabled AS 'users.enabled',\n"
        + "      users.timestamp AS 'users.timestamp',\n"
        + "      users.id AS 'users.id'\n"
        + "  FROM users";

 @Autowired
 private JdbcTemplate jt;

 public List<User> getAllUsers() {
 List<User> users = this.jt.query(GET_USERS_SQL, new UserRowMapper());

    return users;
    }

}
```

//entity class

```
public class User {

private final long id;
private final String username;
private final boolean enabled;
private final Timestamp timestamp;

 public User(long id, String username, boolean enabled, Timestamp timestamp) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.enabled = enabled;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}


 // getters & setters 

 @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "User{" + "id=" + id + ", username=" + username + ", enabled=" + enabled + ", timestamp=" + timestamp + '}';
}
```

}

The code is all working fine but this can lead to problems such as boilerplate code
Anyone know how this can be changed to simpler version ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring Jpa Data:

```
    @Repository
    public interface UserDAO  extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
     }
```

A Service class :

```
 @Service   
 public UserService { 

      @Resource
      private UserDoa dao;

       @Transactional
       public List<User> getAllUsers() {
           List<User> users =  dao.findAll();
           return users;
        }
  }
```

This is a list of [query creation mechanism](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

you can Also use [queryDsl and Specifications](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) from more complicated scenarios and you can get rid of nearly all the sql boiler plate way.

Comment: Would I need to include my queries somewhere ? and I think I would need to modify my config files e.g. pom.xml and servlet.xml ?

Comment: You can use `@NamedQuery` to include your queries in case you need them, and yes you will have to add spring data artifact dependency but it is worth it in my opinion.

Comment: @r93 this list of tutorials might help http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-jpa-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring Data JPA you can have much of the code being generated for you.

Main Steps:

1. Add a dependency to spring-data-jpa
2. Enable JPA Repositories
3. Create a repository interface extending CrudRepository

You can now use the repository. The implementation will be generated.

See detailed instructions: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts